# Fail to bind tomcat to port 5060 - no mappable port

Tags: java, tomcat, tcp

I'm trying to start the port 5060 on my tomcat but I got this error on catalina.out

```
WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads 
  The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MessageProcessorThread-UDP-0.0.0.0/5060] 
  but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread

WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [NioSelector-TCP-0.0.0.0/5060] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread

 INFO [MessageProcessorThread-UDP-0.0.0.0/5060] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel$PingBackTimerTask]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.

catalina.out:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a mappable open port between 5060 and 5080. Firewall problem?
catalina.out:com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a mappable open port between 5060 and 5080. Firewall problem?
 WARNING [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [NioSelector-TCP-0.0.0.0/5060] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread
```

Do you have any why is it happen?

Thank you,

Comment: You already have Tomcat running and all ports between 5060 and 5080 are taken?

Comment: Some other program uses port 5060 (perhaps Asterisk ?) or some other PBX ? - therefore Java can  not bind to this port as its used

Comment: you need to stop all existing or previous java processes that are running already and using the port. use ps-ef | grep java